# Php, is there a way to load a class into a namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces

Lets suppose I have some classes in the global namespace. I don't want to use the namespace keyword in each class, but I have an autoloading mechanism. Can I dynamically set the namespace for the classes? So

```
\src\HTML\Form\Form.php

// namespace HTML\Form

class Form
{
}

\src\Setting\Db.php

// namespace Setting

class Db
{
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: I dont need to manually put a correct namespace definition to about 200 file. Namespace fit to directory structure anyway, so it can be automatized

Comment: Most people do the reverse: the namespaced classname maps to the folder (as per PSR-4).... but adding a namespace keyword to 200 files isn't a lot

Comment: yes but what if I move a sub-directory to another? Doing renaming manually again?

Answer (score 2):

> I dont want to use the namespace keyword in each class

If you don't want use namespace, then don't use it. If your problem is only to use an autoloader then you can simply map each class with its directory path.

```
$srcDir = __DIR__. '/src';
$formDir = $srcDir . '/HTML/Form';
$classesMap = array(
    'Db'   => $srcDir . '/Setting/Db.php',
    'Form' => $formDir . '/Form.php',
);
```

This work would not be necessary if you followed one standard like PSR-0/4 or the (old) PEAR coding standard.

If you're using composer, look [classmap](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap).

> is there a way to load a class into a namespace?

Something like

```
function autoload($class) {
    namespace DynamicNamespace {
        require ('/path/to/classes/'. $class);
    };
}
```

is **not** allowed.